# Double click not working on secondary monitor - Ubuntu 18.04 in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, multiple-monitors, mouse, monitor, doubleclick

System

- Laptop: Dell XPS 15 9570
- External Monitor: Acer S277HK
- Host system: Windows 10, version 1803
- Virtual Box: 6.0.6
- Guest system: Ubuntu 18.04

Issue:

- Double-click not working on external monitor in guest system (Ubuntu), both for external mouse and touchpad
- system unusable

Further description of behavior:

- Single left and right click working on external monitor in guest system
- It appears that after click respective system button release not triggered
- Double click working fine in host system
- Double click working fine in guest system on internal laptop screen
- If both VBox-screens are on internal laptop screen, double click works

Strategies already tried:

- Stop all VBox-Guest processes

Any additional help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "double click working" in the first place?

Comment: I mean performing a double click (clicking twice with mouse in short interval) on a desktop icon. Is there any other way to define a double-click?

Comment: Not entirely sure if this was the root cause, but installing ubuntu 18.04 with VirtualBox 5.2 did work like a charm concerning graphics and mouse.

Comment: @Thomas Did you resolve this situation? I have the same scenario for Ubuntu Desktop 20.04

Comment: If you found the solution pls, give me a hand here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377440/mouse-single-double-click-does-not-work-in-secondary-screen-monitor